# How do I stop my Emachines E443 system from freezing either at the login screen or right after I get in?

Tags: wubi, login-screen, lockup

MAJOR UPDATE: I am no longer using Ubuntu with Wubi, because I like having only one OS on a PC at a time. But, it is running smoothly in VirtualBox 4.1.14, so I'm OK with 12.04 now. Thanks for trying to resolve the issue!

I have an EMachines E443 laptop in which I used the Wubi installer to put 11.10 on my disk. Every time I try to log in, it just freezes before I even see my wallpaper. Either that, or right before I get to type my password. Please help, as I want to use the new Ubuntu!
EDIT:
I have uninstalled Ubuntu using Add/Remove programs. Hoping for the best results on the reinstall! ;)
EDIT 2:
It works!
EDIT 3:
Okay, broken again. For some reason, it only happens on the second boot of the install.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same notebook and had the same issue, and it is something network related; the workaround is entering in BIOS setup and setting Network Boot as first boot method.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ACPI, either in BIOS or via editing kernel parameters in GRUB solves such issue for me on an old PC. On usual installations you can do that by editing this line in /etc/default/grub :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

change it to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

However, Wubi doesn't use GRUB (as far as I know), so I'm not sure how to do that on Wubi.